# Incorrect syntax near "as" in CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

i'm trying to create a new table in my SSMS environment, and in the last step (shown below) i want to create a new column as the opposite of the "meet" column and call it something else, but i get an error because of incorrect syntax near "as". Does anyone have a solution?

```
select a.*, b.meet, case when b.meet=0 then 1 else 0 as meet2
INTO [Database].[View] /* Not the actual name */
from #foundation a
left join #meet_held b
on a.key=b.keyand a.key2=b.key2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typo: a `case` needs an `end`. Voting to close.

Comment: This would be simpler without `case`.  Assuming there are only two values, just use `1 - meet as meet2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select a.*, b.meet, case when b.meet=0 then 1 else 0 end as meet2
  INTO [Database].[View] /* Not the actual name */
  from #foundation a
  left join #meet_held b
  on a.key=b.key and a.key2=b.key2
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed an "End" in my statement... Thx :)